# jQuery changing html text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Been trying to change the innerHTML of some elements either on page load or page save.

Basically when I save the HTML page I want the timestamp to update just that once, not on page load or anything... this way people can see when the status was last updated.

I also want to have it so all I need to do is change the class of the `#status` to `close` and when the page loads it will automatically change the text inside the div.

Here is my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/MD3Wx/1/

**HTML**

```
<div class="lastChange">
    This was last updated on: <span class="timestamp">00:00:00</span>
</div>
<div class="close" id="status">
    OPEN
</div>
<hr />
<div class="comments">
    Comments :<br />
    <span class="timestamp">00:00:00</span> <span class="info">Info</span></div>
```

**JQUERY**

```
var d = new Date();
$('.timestamp').each(function() {
   $(this).html(d.toLocaleString);
});

$(document).ready(function(){
   if($('#status').hasClass("open")){
      $('#status').html("OPEN");
   }
   else{
      $('#status').html("CLOSED");
   }
});
```

Comment: it should be `$(this).html(d.toLocaleString());` - http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/5WNAR/1/ - because `toLocaleString` is a method - what else do you want to have

Comment: @ArunPJohny well that just fixed everything... hahaha silly mistake. I was originally using javascript and innerHTML and I had it right there, but when I changed it over I forgot about the parenthesis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call the function `toLocaleString`, instead of just passing it as reference to the `html()` method.

```
var d = new Date();
$('.timestamp').each(function () {
    $(this).html(d.toLocaleString());
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/5WNAR/)

Comment: is there anyway that I can have the date so that it only changes when I save the HTML page, because as of now everytime I refresh the page the time changes, which doesn't help me at all.

Comment: what do you mean by saving the page

Comment: if you want to have the time of the comment then you can't do it in the client side you need to store the time in the server along with the comment and while displaying it back you need to fetch the time along with the comment back from the server

Comment: so what language would I need to do that in? .net?

Answer (score 1):

```
var d = new Date();
$('.timestamp').each(function () {
    $(this).html(d.toLocaleString());  //toLocaleString is a method so close with ()
});

$(document).ready(function () {
    if ($('#status').hasClass("open")) {
        $('#status').html("OPEN");
    } else {
        $('#status').html("CLOSED");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I haven't understood the question but I think you want a update of the date every second...

```
setInterval(function(){
    var d = new Date();
    $('.timestamp').each(function() {
       $(this).html(d.toLocaleString());
    });

    $(document).ready(function(){
       if($('#status').hasClass("open")){
          $('#status').html("OPEN");
       }
       else{
          $('#status').html("CLOSED");
       }
    });
}, 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var d = new Date();
$('.timestamp').each(function () {
    $(this).html(d.toLocaleString());  //toLocaleString is a method so close with ()
});
```

This code will work.